# The Application keeps stopping when call the database helper class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

this is my databaseHelper class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.key;
import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N;


public class DatabaseHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SADER";
    private static final String TABLE_NOTES = "notes";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                +KEY_CONTENT + " TEXT, "
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Every time I call this class by  `DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);`,
the application is stopped !!

What can I do and where can I find the error ??

Comment: Any errors? Any logcats?

Comment: It looks like your `CREATE_NOTES_TABLE` is wrong. There is a "," in the end of the string.

Comment: @Mohsen I am new to android studio and I don't know where I find the errors..

Comment: There is a logcat section in below of Android Studio (If you use Android Studio), there you can find any related crashes when you run the app. It should be visible by red colors..

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך Oh my god :( Thank you my friend it worked.. but for the future.. Is there a place where I can find the errors like this ?

Comment: Sadly, no. But you can minimize the error by adding a simple `Log.d` to after the string to check for it.

Comment: Why not to use the android architecture components? Take a look at Room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an extra character of `,` in your CREATE TABLE statement string:

```
String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES + " ( "
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, "
        +KEY_CONTENT + " TEXT, "
        + ")";
```

remove it so it will becomes:

```
String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES + " ( "
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, "
        +KEY_CONTENT + " TEXT "
        + ")";
```

To minimize future error, add a `Log.d` to check if your string is correct like this:

```
String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = ...;

Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = 
 + CREATE_NOTES_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Always surround with a try /catch to isolate the error. Generaly is some SQL syntax error

```
try {

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("DatabaseHelper", e.getMessage());
}
```